# Vertical align in css

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have an `<div>` in an `<li>`. In the Div is text, the size of that text changes.

html:

```
<li id="button_welcome"><div>Welcome</div></li>
```

css:

```
#about_nav li{
    height:48px;
    width:130px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
#about_nav li div{
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

how do i get the text to stay in the middle of the `<li>`?

P.S. i have a gradient background on the `<li>` but i removed it because it is bulky.

cheer,

Fraser

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE

If you want to use a gradient for a background, you could try the CSS way; check out the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/F5FEg/1/

Instead, if you want to use an image, it shouldn't affect how the text is positioned since this is a "background" image. If you do get some weird positioning, update your question and show us exactly what the problem is with code/screenshots/fiddle.

---

Give it a `line-height` as tall as the `<li>`...

```
#about_nav li div{
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    line-height: 48px; /* as tall as the li */
}
```

Vertical alignment is a tricky business. Take a look at this article on getting a better understanding on how to `vertical-align` works and how to align things vertically in general...

http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: This and @Homer6's answer handle wrapped text poorly, may be important to OP as he says `the size of that text changes`, but then again he has hard coded the height which doesn't make sense, you could just use padding in that case if you know you only have 1 line of text and explicit height.

Comment: @Madmartigan... well, if you're bringing up wrapping text, then I'll counter argue with the height for `<li>`... if the user plans on having text wrap, he shouldn't be assigning the list item a height

Comment: thanks, that works great, but is there a way to bring the text down a few pixels? its sitting a bit high.

Comment: @FraserK... what do you mean "sitting a bit high"? Can you show me a fiddle?

Comment: @Hristo I totally agree. Even though we have the same answer, I'm going to up vote your answer because I think it's correct.  Cheers.

Comment: I don't think using line-height is a good solution. First of all it is hard coded and second, if you have content inside the div that wraps to two lines, you will see an issue.

Comment: @hristo and @madmartigan, there is only one line of text and these `<li>` tags are for buttons so have a fixed height and also an animated width.

Comment: @Jaspero... dude, I agree, but the poster has hard-coded a height for the list item... if text wraps he's screwed anyway. the issue is beyond the line-height when it comes to wrapping text

Comment: @hristo, there is a gradient background and i would like the text to be centered with that but atm the text is a few pixels to high, so how can i move the text down? padding maybe?

Comment: @FraserK... great! then the line-height should work **if** you know that your list item's height will always be 48px and that the text will **not** wrap. in regards to the gradient bg, update your question with an example and code and we can go from there

Comment: To stop any confusion, the list item is min of 120px wide, and has only one or two words on it, it has been designed not to wrap, and for this particular application it can be more or less hard-coded

Comment: @hristo, the gradient code is irrelevant here as it cannot be changed, all that is needed is to 'push' the text down a few pixels, would adding padding work?

Comment: @FraserK... I mean... if you want to add padding to the `<div>`, you can and that should fix your issue. Alternatively, you could change the value of the line-height and that should also move the text up/down. But I don't like these solutions. There is a better way to do it.

Comment: @hristo if there is a better way do you want to tell me then, ill create a fiddle.

Comment: @FraserK... make a fiddle with your code and the image you're using.

Comment: @everyone, here is the fiddle of what actually happens, ignore the messy javascript atm. http://jsfiddle.net/R5n8V/

Comment: @FraserK... I don't know, it looks centered to me. Use either `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` to move the text up/down. It looks fine for me. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The magic is to use simulate a table layout with css

```
#about_nav li{
    height:48px;
    width:130px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    display:table-row;
}
#about_nav li div{
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the line-height the same value as the height. The font size should be smaller than the height.

```
<style>
    #my_div{
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: center;
    }    
</style>
<div id="my_div">My DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Hristos answer a lot =) Heres another solution:

```
#about_nav li{
    height:48px;
    width:130px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    border:1px solid;
}
#about_nav li div{
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
    padding-right:10px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

If you set the height and width of the div you can use the vertical -align property

## See an Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3asEN/

Answer (score -2):

Add text-align: center; to the div or the li.

Comment: i need to vertical align not horizontal